# Create folder in /var/mobile/Library/APPNAME on jailbroken iOS device with iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I'm trying to create a folder inside /var/mobile/Library/MyAppName. I read on internet that I must use the command:

```
mkdir(“/var/mobile/Library/YOURAPPNAME”, 0755);
```

but xcode cannot recognize that command... how can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `mkdir()`, add

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
```

You can get this information from "man 2 mkdir" on the command line,
or from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html.